# $.getJSON doesn't work but having the JSON object in the script works

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I am trying to dynamically create a simple `select` which contains an object's property as the `option` based on some constraints.

Everything works fine when my JSON is a part of the script.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uHbZt/)

The code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*$.getJSON('input.json',function(data){
        alert('inside');
    });*/

    /*$.getJSON("inputjson.json", function(data){
        // I have placed alert here previously and realized it doesn't go into here
        console.log("datd");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,4));
    });*/



    var jsonList = 
    {
        "json_data" : {
            "data" : [
                {
                    "data" : "A node",
                    "metadata" : { id : 23 },
                    "children" : [ "Child 1", "A Child 2" ]
                },
                {
                    "attr" : { "id" : "li.node.id1" , "level" : "3" , "name" : "Ragini" },
                    "data" : {
                        "title" : "Long format demo",
                        "attr" : { "href" : "#" }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "attr" : { "id" : "li.node.id1" , "level" : "3" , "name" : "Rag" },
                    "data" : {
                        "title" : "Long format demo",
                        "attr" : { "href" : "#" }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "attr" : { "id" : "li.node.id1" , "level" : "4" , "name" : "Skyrbe" },
                    "data" : {
                        "title" : "Long format demo",
                        "attr" : { "href" : "#" }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }


    var newObject = jsonList.json_data.data;
    var listItems= "";

    $form = $("<form></form>");
    $('#form_container').append($form);

    var $selectContainer = $("<select id=\"selectId\" name=\"selectName\" />");

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonList.json_data.data.length; i++)
    {
        if(jsonList.json_data.data[i].hasOwnProperty("attr") && jsonList.json_data.data[i].attr.level == 3)
        {
            listItems+= "<option value='" + jsonList.json_data.data[i].attr.name + "'>" + jsonList.json_data.data[i].attr.name + "</option>";
        }
    }
    $($selectContainer).html(listItems);
    $($form).append($selectContainer);
});
```

But when I try to put the JSON into a seperate .json file and use `$.getJSON` , I am not having any success . Basically , the control never comes into it.

This is the code I have written for `$.getJSON`

```
$.getJSON('input.json',function(data){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,4));
});
```

Can someone please point out what my mistake is.

Cheers,
Harsha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to make the select element before the getJSON call has finished. Put the rest of your code into the callback function of your getJSON function, like so:

```
$.getJSON("inputjson.json", function(data){
    // I have placed alert here previously and realized it doesn't go into here
    console.log("datd");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,4));
    var newObject = jsonList.json_data.data;
    var listItems= "";

    $form = $("<form></form>");
    $('#form_container').append($form);
    // etc
});
```

Also note that you have a typo and some unneeded quotes - `console.log("datd");` should be `console.log(data);` (unless you really did just want to put the word 'datd' into your log).

Comment: Woah , Since both your and @nnnnnn 's answer helped me , I am confused about picking one of the two as the answer!

Comment: You should upvote all answers that helped, and accept the one that helped you the most. If they helped you equally accept the one posted first, or, as Grim says, the one from the person with the lower rep total (so either way that is Grim's answer).

Answer (score 3):

Your `jsonList` variable has a valid object literal, so it will work when included directly in your script like that. But that object literal is not valid JSON, so it will not work when included in a separate file for retrieval via `$.getJSON()` - in JSON all property names need to be quoted. So this line:

```
"metadata" : { id : 23 },
```

...needs to be:

```
"metadata" : { "id" : 23 },
```

Once you fix that you will need to move the code that processed `jsonList` into the callback function that you supply to `$.getJSON()`:

```
$.getJSON('input.json',function(data){
    // do all processing here
});
```

In future if you're having trouble with JSON not working you can validate the JSON using this website: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

If there is any syntax error on you JSON file it will return nothing. $.getJSON is a jquery ajax alias which uses $.parseJSON() in the background (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).
Look, JSON syntax is a little different from Javascript literal objects syntax, so if you miss a quote in a variable like you did below, it won't work as expected.

```
"metadata" : { id : 23 }
```